# Accessing all unknown columns in mutate function of r

Tags: r, dplyr

```
  df <- tibble::tribble(  ~sev_curve, ~curve_type,  ~trend_date, ~weight,
                          "MILO",  'HOSPITALS',   '7/1/2020',      0.4,
                          'ALSO',  'PHYSICIANSC', '7/1/2020',      0.6)


df %>% mutate(new_column=#calls function on all columns of df)
```

So the above is roughly what I need. The df data.frame can have a number of different columns that the next line of code may not know about. But it needs to call a function on all of those columns to create a new column.

How do I access all columns from the df in the mutate function?

Comment: You can use `mutate_at` or `mutate_all`  Which of the columns are unknown?  `df %>% mutate_all(list(new = ~ n_distinct(.)))`

Comment: do you need to use mutate?

Comment: @akrun sev_curve and weight are known. The rest are unknown

Comment: @Mike no i don't necessarily need mutate

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(-one_of(c("sev_curve", "weight"))), list(new = ~ n_distinct(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  sev_curve curve_type  trend_date weight curve_type_new trend_date_new
#  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>          <int>          <int>
#1 MILO      HOSPITALS   7/1/2020      0.4              2              1
#2 ALSO      PHYSICIANSC 7/1/2020      0.6              2              1
```

Or without `one_of`

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(-c("sev_curve", "weight")), list(new = ~ n_distinct(.)))
```